# Jquery nestable / initialize list from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the jquery nestable plugin (https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable/blob/master/jquery.nestable.js) to generate a nestable list.

Generation of a json output and save it into a database is not a problem.

Example of json generate by this plugin :

```
[{"id":4,"children":[{"id":3}]}]
```

The question is : How can I construct the nestable list from the same json array ?

Comment: What's the expected output you want, what have you tried?

Comment: Have a look at this start : http://jsfiddle.net/burakoztirpan/53WSc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just form the required html from the array you have. Just wrap it up in a function that handles the nested elements (can be done by calling on itself) and returns the `<ol>` list.

```js
var tarr = [{"id":4,"children":[{"id":3}]}];

function listify(strarr) {
  var l = $("<ol>").addClass("dd-list");
  $.each(strarr, function(i, v) {
    var c = $("<li>").addClass("dd-item"),
      h = $("<div>").addClass("dd-handle").text("Item " + v["id"]);
    l.append(c.append(h));
    if (!!v["children"])
      c.append(listify(v["children"]));
  });
  return l;
}

var list = listify(tarr);
$("#test").append(list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: if you want to hide the id, but save it, you can do the following:  `var c = $("<li>").addClass("dd-item").attr("data-id", v["id"]), ` , if you want to add a description: `h = $("<div>").addClass("dd-handle").text(v["thenameyougave"]) `

Answer (score 1):

we all have seen how to add items dynamically to nestable. I have written this code, where in you can create nestable items from JSON object.

```
var json =  [{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "Payment Terms",
  "children": [{
    "id": 2,
    "content": "PT1"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "content": "PT2"
  }]
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "content": "Delivery Terms",
  "children": [{
    "id": 5,
    "content": "dt1"
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "content": "dt2"
  }]
}];

Function to create nestable :

function makeNestableListUsingJSONArray(jsonArray, root) {

  if (typeof root === 'undefined') {
    root = $('body');
  }
  var $div = $('<div id="nestable"><ol class="dd-list"></ol></div>');
  root.append($div);
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
    var $li = $("<li class='dd-item' data-id='" + jsonArray[i].id + "'><div class='dd-handle'><span class='dd-content'>" + jsonArray[i].content + "</span></div></li>");
    root.find('ol.dd-list:first').append($li);    

    if (typeof jsonArray[i].children !== 'undefined') {
      makeNestableListUsingJSONArray(jsonArray[i].children, $li);
    }
  }
  $('#nestable').nestable({maxDepth:2});
}

call the function 
makeNestableListUsingJSONArray(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ozan's answer works well but if you need more advanced configuration then here is the link https://github.com/RamonSmit/Nestable2